# Converting a re.sub command line to Apps Script

Tags: regex, python-2.7, google-apps-script

I need to strip off the ending variations of our SKUs in order to import into another system. Here are a few Examples:

I have a Python script that does this (and much more), but I just need to  remove SKU variations on Google Sheets as part of an Apps Script. Here is the part of the Python code that removes the ending variations of our SKUs.

```
sku = re.sub(r"(-[a-zA-Z])([0-9]{1,3})$", r"\1", sku)
sku = re.sub(r"(^(?:\w+-){3}\w+)-[0-9]{1,3}$", r"\1", sku)
```

I believe the 1st code is saying to look for all SKUs ending with a "-,letter,number", and remove everything after the "-,letter".

```
 MGGQ2-B2      = MGGQ2-B
 C810-T7ZT-C89 = C810-T7ZT-C
```

I believe the 2nd Code is saying to look for all SKUs containing 4 dashes, and remove everything starting at the 4th dash.

```
MC965A-4-128-17-1  = MC965A-4-128-17
MMGG2A-8-256-16-89 = MMGG2A-8-256-16
```

I have written a HUGE macro to Find and Replace every possible SKU Variation, but this script is only 2 lines. Is this enough information to apply this to a Google Sheets macro?

Comment: `Is this enough information to apply this to a Google Sheets macro?` Yes. Apply the same regex in js.

Comment: It is really the same regex in JS, just the replacement backreferences are `$1`, not `\1`. There may be issues with non-capturing groups though, convert them into capturing ones and adjust the backreferences.